# Difference between int* array[] and int (*array)[]

Tags: c++, c

I am wondering what is the difference between `int* array[5]` and `int (*array)[5]`?

When I try the access of 2D array works with both of them. I could even accessing it with single int* array but have to multiply row*columns because they all are reserved consecutively in the memory.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: Well (referring to the forms in the title), on one `sizeof array` is a compile error, and on the other `sizeof array[0]` is.